# WRONG MYSQL QUERY

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table where "meeting_id" is a colum.
I need to show only results that is related to this meeting ID on table POLLS

The actual query is:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(pa.title ORDER BY pa.id) AS answers 
                        FROM polls p 
                        LEFT JOIN poll_answers pa ON pa.poll_id = p.id 
                        GROUP BY p.id');
```

I have tried without success:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(pa.title WHERE meeting_id = '.$meeting_id.' ORDER BY pa.id) AS answers 
                        FROM polls p 
                        LEFT JOIN poll_answers pa ON pa.poll_id = p.id 
                        GROUP BY p.id');
```

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WHERE clause doesn't go inside `GROUP_CONCAT()`, it goes after `FROM` and `JOIN`.

You should also use parameters, not variable concatenation.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(pa.title ORDER BY pa.id) AS answers 
                        FROM polls p 
                        LEFT JOIN poll_answers pa ON pa.poll_id = p.id 
                        WHERE p.meeting_id = :meeting_id
                        GROUP BY p.id');
$stmt->bindParam(':meeting_id', $meeting_id);
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you